# How to find grouptype attribute of a Group AD object using PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm using the [`GetGroups()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357862(v=vs.110).aspx) method for getting all groups from a PrincipalSearchResult. But I couldn't find a way to get the `groupType` attribute of a Group object. Do you have any idea how I can get the `groupType` attribute from a [`Principal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal(v=vs.110).aspx) object?

[image]

EDIT:

I only see a property: `IsSecurityGroup`. But It's impossible to know if the group is:

- Global distribution group
- Domain local distribution group
- Universal distribution group
- Global security group
- Domain local security group
- Universal security group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information from the `GroupScope` property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupscope(v=vs.110).aspx

`Global` - The group's scope is global.

`Local` - The scope of the group is local.

`Universal` - The scope of the group is universal.

In conjunction with the `IsSecurityGroup` property. (i.e. if its not a security group its a distribution group)

Comment: In the meantime I have also found that property. Thanks btw